# How Do I Use the app.config file with a Test Project

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, configuration

I using unit testing, to ensure that I can read connect string information from the ConnectStrings section of my app.config file.  This works fine in the application proper, However when I attempt to generate a unit test for this under the Test Project, the dll.config file is being ignored, and the connectstring info from the machine.config file is being retrieved instead.  How do I ensure that my tests read from the correct config file?

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using, the one built into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Your test project must have its own App.Config file.

Answer (score 3):

You should add an `app.config` file to to your test project and populate it with the necessary values.  You may ask "Why can't I use the existing app.config in my project?"  The real answer is probably out there but personally I like it this way because it means my test project never points at my production environment.